# Missing return statement method

Tags: java, methods, return-type

I have the following method:

```
public int getValue()
{
  if (currentState == COUNTING)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
    {
      value = i;
      return value;
    }

  }
  else
    return super.getValue();   
}
```

I am getting the following error: Missing return statement.

the purpose of the method is if the state is the counting state, the value should increment from 0 to 99, and return the value after each incrementation. If the state is not the counting state, it should use the getValue method from the superclass.

Comment: Am I missing something, or will you ALWAYS return 0 when you enter the first if?

Comment: I have added above the purpose of the method. I am trying to return the value after each incrementation.

Comment: you can't count like this, 'i' is local variable for the function 'getValue()', it dies when the function ends, you need to define some class variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get the error as there is one case that "theoretically" you may not return anything:

```
if (currentState == COUNTING)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
    {
      value = i;
      return value;
    }
// right here
}
```

Now, it is clear to me (and you) that you will not get there, but not to the compiler.

Apart from this, the return inside the loop makes no sense, as you are going to enter it once, when `i` is zero, and return it, but that's another story which I can't help with because it's not clear to me what's the purpose of this function.

Comment: Additionally, the 'for' block will stop after the first iteration - when you call return, it exits the function.

It also seems odd that you appear to be returning a global variable after setting it equal to the indexer.  You may want to reconsider your program logic; what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Binyamin Sharet How could i change it so a failure return type is added? I mean what could i return in that position?

Comment: @Binyamin Sharet the purpose of the method is if the state is the counting state, the value should increment from 0 to 99, and return the value after each incrementation. If the state is not the counting state, it should use the getValue method from the superclass.

Comment: You can't return more than one value at a time from a function, maybe your counter should be a class member.

Comment: @BinyaminSharet Actually no sorry, i want to return the last value returned by the for loop

Comment: But you will always return 99, won't you?

Comment: @akshai5050, I think you have a misunderstanding about how the return statement works.  When you call "return", function execution ends and returns immediately.  The for loop will never return anything but 0.

Answer (score 3):

What if you enter the `if` but never enter the `for` loop? no return will be reached.
You have to add a return at the end of your method that could return a *failure* value for example.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler can't know is `i<99` condition always true or no. If no, in case when `currentState == COUNTING` method won't return anything. That's why you're getting error. But anyway, why do you need `for` loop when you can just return 0 ? Actually in case when `currentState` equals `COUNTING` your method will return 0 in the first iteration.